# Pre-fill form with local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, local-storage, ejs

I'm loading questions from a JSON into my EJS template and want to populate each field from localStorage. The following saves the last value of each dropdown, text, and slider element:

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
    select[i].value = localStorage.getItem(i);
}
jQuery("select").change(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
        localStorage.setItem(i, select[i].value);
    }
});
```

I repeat this for all `"input"` tags. The issue is that the `select` values also get passed into `text` and `slider` — and vice versa (i.e. if I enter values for `text` and `slider`, they overwrite the `select` values, except they are left blank).

My end goal is to save each form-fields' most recent value so that my entries are not lost when I refresh the page.

Comment: Well, you're using `i` as the key. Assuming your using the same code for `input`s, you're bound to have some overlap. Use a composite (i.e., `\`select-${i}\`` for the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a lot more elegant to create a *single* localStorage entry representing your saved values, rather than pollute LS with many entries for each field. I would recommend something like this:

```
function save() {
  const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  // select other element types
  // ...
  const selectValues = [...selects].map(select => select.value);
  const textValues = [...textInputs].map(textInput => textInput.value);
  const sliderValues = [...sliderInputs].map(sliderInput => sliderInput.value);
  const savedObj = { selectValues, textValues, sliderValues };
  localStorage.savedFormValues = JSON.stringify(savedObj);
}
```

That way, you only create a single entry in localStorage, and each entry type is quite distinct. Then, to get the values, just do the same thing in reverse:

```
function populate() {
  const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  // ...
  const { selectValues, textValues, sliderValues } = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedFormValues);
  selectValues.forEach((selectValue, i) => selects[i].value = selectValue);
  // ...
```